# Cant reinstall my Android app on my device anymore, after deinstalling the App. (Error type 3: MainActivity does not exist)

Tags: android, installation, adb, device

I need a little bit of help with my new problem.
I'm programming an android app with Android studio and everything worked fine.
I always tested my app on my device (Xiaomi Mi 8).

I tried to reinstall my application, after this I always got the error

> Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.cartalk/com.example.cartalk.Activities.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>       Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.cartalk/.Activities.MainActivity }
>       Error type 3
>       Error: Activity class {com.example.cartalk/com.example.cartalk.Activities.MainActivity} does not exist.
>
> Error while Launching activity

The issue can be reconstructed. I would say that there are some data left, which wasn't deleted with the uninstallation.

But I don't know how to delete them.

I tried:

```
adb deinstall "package name" (can't find the package anymore)
```

I also used CCleaner (didn't work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved my issue.

What I did:

I build an apk.

Used the comment

```
adb install -r -t app-debug.apk
```

app-debug.apk can be found under ProjectFolder\app\build\outputs\apk\debug

After the success, i tried the adb uninstall again.

```
adb uninstall "package name"
```

Now, the package could be found and deinstalled completely!

Comment: Thank you it worked for me, in my case  it was:


adb uninstall "com.example.app"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem With a Xiaomi S2 with a Flutter app also with a native android app.
To uninstall the package, connect the device and then go to:

**C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools**

Open your terminal:

```
adb uninstall com.example.hello_world
```